# Mistake in Chi-Square Distribution

Tags: r, distribution, chi-squared

I'm trying to generate chi-square random variables according to the following algorithm:

[image]

where a(i) are independent, standard normal random variables witn m even and odd 
respectively.

Wikipedia gives the following definition:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Definition

The code I wrote is:

```
dch = double(1000)
t = double(1)
for(i in 1:1000) {
  for(j in 1:m) {
    x = runif(1, 0, 1)
    t = t + x*x
  }
  dch[i] = t
}
```

but I am getting the wrong density plot.
So, where is/are the mistake/s and how can I fix them?

Comment: Well, you don't define `m`. You use uniform random variables not normal random variables. Those are the mistakes I see.

Comment: Also, I can't really read your PNG image very well, but the product seems to go from 2 to m/2, where as you are going from 1 to m. And the log of the product can be rewritten as a sum of logs. You are summing but you don't have any logs...

Comment: Of course, you can't generally take the log of a normal RV, so perhaps your code (uniform random variable) is correct and your description (standard normal random variable) is the problem there.

Comment: I did according to the wiki. because I don't understand how it could be from 2 to m/2 if m = 2 (which is my case). so i change m to 2, but it still incorrect. even more :(

Comment: If you have two degrees of freedom, the wiki says let X be random uniform on (0, 1), then -2 * log(X) ~ ChiSq(2). So maybe you should just do `x = runif(1000); dch = -2 * log(x)`. Comparing `hist(dch, 20)` to `hist(rchisq(1000), 20)` it looks spot on.

Answer (score 2):

As Gregor suggested in comments, you are misinterpreting the inputs to the algorithm.  One way to get a Chi-squared with m degrees of freedom is to sum m independent squared standard normals, but that's not the only distributional relationship we know.  It turns out that a Chi-squared(2) is the same as an exponential distribution with a mean of 2, and exponentials are straightforward to generate with [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), a.k.a. inversion.  So in principle, if m is even you want to generate m/2 exponential(2)'s and sum them.  If m is odd, do the same but add one additional standard normal squared.

What all that means is that a straightforward implementation would have you doing m/2 logarithmic evaluations to generate the exponentials. It turns out you can apply the [superposition](http://www.randomservices.org/random/poisson/Splitting.html) property of exponentials so you only have to do one log evaluation.  Since transcendental functions are computationally expensive, this improves the efficiency of the algorithm.

When the dust settles - the `z` on the second line of your algorithm is a standard normal, but the `a`'s are Uniform(0,1)'s, ***not*** normals.